# Largest linear Independent subset of n polynomials

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-algebra

There are **n** polynomials in below format:

```
x(i)  
x(i)+1  
x(i)+x(k)  
x(i)+x(k)+1  
...
```

We want to extract largest possible linear independant subset of above polynomials
I have tried Gassian elimination but it's too slow.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: is the next term of the form `x(i)+x(k)+ x(m)`

Comment: Have you read about QR-Decomposition? You can (should) use some numeric library for it, instead of implementing it yourself.

Comment: You might want to give some code (even if just pseudocode) to show your current approach.

Comment: @UmNyobe no. suppose there are n terms of c.x(i) (i=1 to n and c=0 or 1). During a special process, some x(i)'s will have c=1.At the end of process, 1 is added or not. For example: 1+x(0), x(45), x(1)+x(2)+x(14) , ...

Comment: @marc I have not found any library that includes this operation.

Comment: @samsam114: You write "I have tried Gaussian elimination but it is too slow". Ergo you have some (albeit slow) code, no?

Comment: samsam: Just for clarification - is your notation `c.x(i)` the same as `c*(x^i)` ?

Comment: @samsam114 if you don't take advantage of a specific property of your polynomials (aka matrix) you cannot do better than algorithms which are O(n^3), such as Gaussian elimination

Comment: @HW i is index of x, for example x2, x54, rtc

Comment: There are some implementation in MATLAB, but MATLAB is too slow for a cryptanalysis process

Comment: By the way, we can produce a Matrix from that coefficients; right? Is there any way to find Largest linear Independent subset of rows???

Answer (score 0):

As I searched, the solution is to use SVD or QR Decomposition.
These are the case.
Regards